# Dealing with wood pest in roof truss

Tags: wood

I have recently discovered the following signs of wood pest in my roof truss:

[image]

A few other rafters seem to have the same type of wood pest.

Which insect am I dealing with? Is this a woodworm, a house longhorn or something different?
And what´s the best way to get rid of that specific insect?

Comment: I am moving this to DIY per AlaskaMan's comment

Comment: Try to get photo of undisturbed frass or powder under the beam - helps with ID.